# JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Not"

Tags: json

I am working through the react-native tutorial at http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#fetching-real-data and after adding the function

```
fetchData: function() {
  fetch(REQUEST_URL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      this.setState({
        movies: responseData.movies,
      });
    })
    .done();
},
```

to the AwesomeProject object and then reloading the iOS simulator, I get the error `JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Not"`. Since I have not written any JSON, I do not know where this error could be coming from.

Answer (score 4):

I had missed a character in REQUEST_URL. Therefore the request for that URL was returning a `404 Not Found`, of which the first non-json token was of course, `Not`. I determined this by running `curl` on the url, but you can also check it by visiting the url in a browser.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. It helped me in my case.